# Find Instance of SQL Server / Database on a Server

Tags: sql-server

I've been asked by my boss to determine: "*Is there a SQL Database installed on the 'Server_Name' server?*".

If I understand correctly, a SQL Server Database can only exist in an instance of a SQL Server. 
Is that correct?

If so:
How do I determine if there is an instance of SQL Server installed on a particular Server?

The Server in question is where I use SSMS to do all the T-SQL queries and reporting and Visual Studio for my SSRS reports.

The Server has the following on separate Drives:
SQL Data, SQL Log, SQL Tempdb.

On the C:\Program Files - there is a 'SQL Server' folder ... which has several sub folders:

[image]

... but beyond that, I don't know what to look for to answer the question from my boss.

I would appreciate any help or pointers.

Comment: what I do to find-out is that, I check the List of "Windows Services" and search with "Sql Server". Usually the SQL Server service name will be "SQL Server(<Instance name>)"

Comment: And/or check the installed programs list in the control panel, it'll tell you if SQL Server is installed or not.

Comment: In the Task Manager - Services Tab - there is an item with the Name MSSQLSERVER. Under 'Description' for that item, it says, 'SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)' - and under Status, it says 'Running'. Is that what you are talking about @Amit Kumar?

Comment: @Talay I was talking about windows services screen which you get when you type "services.msc" in run window.

Comment: @AmitKumar, thanks! I was able to see it running in the screen you suggested and that answered my question.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this Powershell command to list the SQL Server Database Engine instances installed on a Windows box:

```
PS C:\>  Get-Service | where { $_.Name -like "MSSQL$*" -or $_.Name -eq "MSSQLSERVER" }
```

Comment: That returned exactly what I mentioned in my question to Amit Kumar above. Thanks! Sorry to pile another related question here - but how do I determine if there are any Databases in that instance of SQL Server?

Comment: Connect to the isntance with SSMS and look.

Comment: Thanks. Your Powershell command answered my question. Appreciate it. I was not able to connect to the instance. I got a 'Login failed ...' message. Thanks for your help.